# AppEngine App works for approx 15minutes then has no access to cloudsql anymore

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Like already mentioned in the title, I am using AppEngine to create an App with Eclipse.
Everything works like a charm locally.

After I deploy, it still works fine. I use the Google API to get Users to log into my application and on top of that I have users connected to that login data in my cloudsql instance. 
After 15 minutes none of the users are found anymore, eventhough they are still in the database. The sql queries fit, because like i said everything works perfect for 15 minutes.

I already read that there is an sql db timeout after 15min, but the db is still running and accessable via sqlworkbench and co and even queries work that way.

Is there a configuration that i might have messed up or is it possible that AppEngine is doing strange things?

I´m happy about all ideas, because I´m dealing with that problem for the last 20h.

Thanks a lot

Ferdinand

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the Session token may have 15 minutes life, so try to refresh the token before it expires.